# PageSpeed - How to reduce Reduce initial server response time and Eliminate render-blocking to increase page speed

Tags: server-setup, magento2.4.5, pagespeed, render-blocking

In gtmetrix, I am facing high initial server response time and render-blocking resources.

[image]

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance enhancing suggestions.

Comment: Maybe in the new year you will have time to post the Additional DB information requested for your workload tuning analysis.  Happy New Year.

Answer (score 1):

These are really two questions, so I'll address them separately.

## Reduce initial server response time

Initial server response time is influenced by many things:

- Server-side PHP code:
  Lots of things can influence this, especially inefficient database calls
  like loading entities in a loop (as opposed to loading the data in a batch
  using resource collections), or waiting for outside API calls to return.
  I recommend installing an APM service like NewRelic on a separate
  development environment to troubleshoot if there are any bottlenecks.
- Default caching:
  Make sure that you are using as much caching as feasible.
  This includes using [Redis for the default cache](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/redis/redis-pg-cache.html)
- Full page caching:
  The best-case scenario is when PHP doesn't need to be used at all to serve
  a page. The best is to use [Varnish](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/varnish/config-varnish.html?lang=en), Fastly, or some other edge cache
  that integrates well with Magento 2.  You may also
  wish to look into various cache warmer extensions from
  third-party vendors, to ensure that your highest traffic pages are
  pre-cached frequently.
- Server hardware:
  Performance problems may be able to be solved by just migrating to newer
  or bigger hardware. Magento 2 is a very CPU-hungry beast, and running on
  CPU-optimized instances usually yield the best performance for your money
  than general-purpose instances. If you can afford it, SSD storage is ideal.
- PHP tuning:
  Enabling PHP opcache and especially the new `opcache.jit` setting in PHP 8+
  can yield some truly remarkable performance improvements if you aren't
  already using them. Note, `opcache.jit` does not play nicely with some
  extensions like NewRelic or IonCube Loader, and it can cause the site to
  break, so definitely test new settings on a separate development environment
  before implementing them on a production server.

## Eliminate render-blocking resources

This is about client-side performance. You want to make sure that any dependencies that are needed to start rendering above-the-fold HTML to the browser are kept small.

- Compress and Minify Javascript and CSS:
  The best performance comes from creating [Advanced Javascript
  Bundles](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/performance-best-practices/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html), which in my experience, can reduce load times by 50%,
  but this can be painstaking to set up.
- Use an efficient theme:
  Lots of themes load *way* too much Javascript, adding dozens of
  RequireJS dependencies to do things that Magento's core libraries
  already provide. Even using Luma as a base theme is pretty heavy.
  Many modern sites are choosing the [Hyva theme](https://www.hyva.io/) or going
  completely headless for this reason.
- [Avoid Jquery UI Compat mode like the plague](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/293826/15602): It's a very heavy
  library, and you should only load exactly what you need, not the
  whole thing.
- Use smaller, less visually complex images: Vector graphics like SVG
  can be rendered on any screen size and compress great. Large,
  full-page ads or videos look great on billboards, but they aren't a
  good fit for ecommerce.
- Tune product thumbnail sizes: Your theme's view.xml file contains
  the standard product image sizes that Magento 2 will create
  automatically. Make sure that these match the maximum size that
  your design can actually utilize. It makes no sense to download a
  500px wide image and have the browser size it down if your CSS
  limits the image display area to 80px.
- Use a CDN: This is already pointed out by PageSpeed, but it impacts
  render blocking as well.
- Use efficient image formats: Image formats like WebP can save a
  lot of space, and some CDNs can provide this automatically. However,
  taking the time to run your high-res images through compression
  like Adobe Photoshop's Save for Web feature can also go a long ways
  towards making compression good by default. Even the inexpensive
  Photoshop Elements has this feature.
- Defer JS as much as possible: If you can, lazy-load expensive
  Javascript libraries like Google Recaptcha until they are absolutely
  needed, like the user focuses a form that uses it. Doing so does
  require some coding experience, but it can save significant load
  time. The following sample code is from https://dev.to/uf4no/improve-page-performance-lazy-loading-recaptcha-442o,
  to illustrate this technique.

  ```html
  <script>

   function sendForm() {
     document.getElementById('contactForm').submit();
   }

   // Function that loads recaptcha on form input focus
   function reCaptchaOnFocus() {
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
     var script = document.createElement('script')
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'
     head.appendChild(script);

     // remove focus to avoid js error:
     document.getElementById('subName').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaOnFocus)
     document.getElementById('subEmail').removeEventListener('focus', reCaptchaOnFocus)
   };
   // add initial event listener to the form inputs
   document.getElementById('subName').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaOnFocus, false);
   document.getElementById('subEmail').addEventListener('focus', reCaptchaOnFocus, false);

  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Time to first byte optimization**:

1. Use a PHP profiler to find code bottlenecks. In many cases it's a 3rd-party extension or a poorly written theme file. My personal choice - tideways profiler, it's free the first 14 days or so, it should be enough for an initial audit.
2. Use Varnish as a Full Page Caching Application (recommended by Adobe).
3. Do a 3rd-party extensions audit. Turn them off one by one and see if it affects server response time.

**Eliminate render-blocking resources**:

1. Move all JavaScript to the bottom. I believe the latest Magento 2.4.6 already does that. If not - find an extension.
2. Remove unused CSS and JS from all pages. Google Chrome Coverage tab will help, it shows what's being used and what's not. See a screenshot of this site and that 90%+ of stacks.css isn't being used.[image]
3. Identify critical and non-critical CSS. Critical CSS is what it takes to render above-the-fold content. Inline critical CSS and move everything else to the bottom.

Always test, test, test. Do a cross-browser testing to make sure your layout is OK with all the changes. Good luck!